# How to create type that makes it unknown before another type?

Tags: typescript

I get this error when I try to convert my view to PIXI.Container.

[image]

So my solution is `view as unknown as PIXI.Container` but I want to replace the `as unknown as PIXI.Container` part with something more simple like `as UnknownContainer` how is this possible?

Comment: Could you share some more information like what you're trying to achieve? It's not sufficient to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> want to replace the as unknown as PIXI.Container part with something more simple like as UnknownContainer how is this possible?

It is not possible without changing the properties of either type. I would just use a [double assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#double-assertion) as suggested. Double assertions are there to prevent you from making simple assertion mistakes.